# How should I perform the task

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, devops

I have created hosts file in gitlab as follows I want to encrypt password and I want to use it.
Hosts file as follows

[aix]
tusk12
raid12
[aix:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=San

ansible_ssh_password="{{ ssh_pass }}"
ansible_connection=ssh

How should I pass value to ansible_ssh_password how should I use it in gitlab.

I mentioned ansible_ssh_password=san123 value and I encrypted whole file. I don't want to encrypt whole file I want to encrypt only ansible_ssh_password value and I want to use it in gitlab.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please read the guide [ask]. There are literally millions of unanswered questions on this site, so be sure to use a very descriptive name for your question to help answerers and other users find your question. Additionally, make sure you use [code formatting](/help/formatting) where appropriate. Please [edit] your question to make these changes. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.